# How to store details of rows based on dropdown list selected in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Below is my code where i am genrating a dynamic table and just want to save particulars rows based on dropdown selected and then clicking on update button

```
                  <b-field>
                    <b-select name="contacted" id="" v-on:change="onChangeSite($event)">
                      <option value="contacted">Contacted</option>
                      <option value="not_contacted">Not Contacted</option>
                    </b-select>
                  </b-field>
```

Please suggest how to save value from options

Comment: see used method for above code                                                                                                             methods:{
    onChange: function(e){
        var id = e.target.value;
        var fraud_flag = e.target.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].fraud;
        console.log('id ',id );
        console.log('name ',fraud_flag );
       }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use Vue js and a library for example Vuetify, you can get value by this way:

```
        <v-select
          v-model="contacted"
          :items="contactedList"
          ***item-value="id"
          ***item-text="title"
        ></v-select>
```

but if you won't use this type of select box, you can get value by this way:

```
        <select name="contacted" id="" v-on:change="onChangeSite($event)">
            <option value="contacted">Contacted</option>
            <option value="not_contacted">Not Contacted</option>
        </select>
```

js file:

```
  methods: {
    onChangeSite(e) {
      console.log(e.target.value);
    },
}
```

Comment: I need to store the multiple rows based on dropdown values of these rows in a list, so that later i can push these rows to mongo db,   (for example i need to store row with dropdoen value of contacted)